# HTML5 Video: Show Loader/Spinner between Video & Poster

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I want to show a loader in a Video.js player while my video is being loaded from S3 bucket.

I have a Video.js player which shows a "Play" button, when this button is clicked the player shows a black screen until the video is loaded from S3 bucket. How can  I show a loader in place of that black screen?

Comment: instead of 'want to' it would be helpful for everybody here if you could explain what you have tried so far, and what is the exact 'problem' you are facing...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think I have explained the issue in second paragraph in the question itself.

Comment: Did you try  `poster` attribute https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/options.md#poster ? can you provide some code?

Comment: Yes.. I have poster attribute working fine, I want to have another image after poster disappears when clicked on play icon.

Answer (score 3):

I have also face the same problem in the same regards
Added custom "waiting" event and removed it on "play" event

```
player.on("waiting", function ()
{
    this.addClass("vjs-custom-waiting");
});
player.on("playing", function ()
{
    this.removeClass("vjs-custom-waiting");
});
```

CSS values

```
.vjs-custom-waiting .vjs-loading-spinner
{
    display: block;
}
.video-js.vjs-custom-waiting .vjs-loading-spinner:before,
.video-js.vjs-custom-waiting .vjs-loading-spinner:after
{
    /* I just copied the same animation as in the default css file */
    -webkit-animation: vjs-spinner-spin 1.1s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8) infinite, vjs-spinner-fade 1.1s linear infinite;
    animation: vjs-spinner-spin 1.1s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8) infinite, vjs-spinner-fade 1.1s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off @nizam's answer:

```
.video-js.vjs-paused:not(.vjs-has-started) .vjs-loading-spinner {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

.video-js.vjs-paused:not(.vjs-has-started) .vjs-loading-spinner,
.video-js.vjs-paused:not(.vjs-has-started) .vjs-loading-spinner {
    -webkit-animation: vjs-spinner-spin 1.1s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8) infinite, vjs-spinner-fade 1.1s linear infinite;
    animation: vjs-spinner-spin 1.1s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.8) infinite, vjs-spinner-fade 1.1s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, i solved it by using event listeners for HTML5 media events and showing\hiding my spinner accordingly.

Media Events i listented for (source: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents)):

> `waiting` - Playback has stopped because the next frame is not available, but the user agent expects that frame to become available in due course.
>
> `canplaythrough` - The user agent estimates that if playback were to be started now, the media resource could be rendered at the current playback rate all the way to its end without having to stop for further buffering.

```
var video = videojs(#id); //Videojs object
var videoEl = $('video'); //Video element

video.on('waiting', function(event) {
    //Check another spinner element doesn't exist before adding a new one
    if(!videoEl.next('.spinner').length)
        videoEl.after(<div class="spinner"></div>);
});

video.on('canplaythrough', function(event) {
    //Fade spinner out and remove it.
    videoEl.next('.spinner')
        .fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
});
```

**Note:** that the reason i'm checking if the spinner already exists in the `waiting` event listener, is because i noticed that sometimes when seeking the event if fired more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late 5 years but one posibility was do this video visibility = hidden and throw at async () and await video.play(), and in this moment do visbility of video 'visible' another time.

It's a little trick